# Protobuf-net generic inheritance and closed constructed generic type

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a fairly complex inheritance hierarchy including generics and we are trying to use protobuf .net for serialization purposes. Unfortunately it does not seem to be able to handle this case correctly. This is how the hierarchy looks like.

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(GenericBaseClass<object>))]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(GenericBaseClass<string>))]
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {

        public int BaseProperty1 { set; get; }
        public int BaseProperty2 { set; get; }

        public BaseClass()
        {

        }

    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1002, typeof(GenericDerivedClass<object>))]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1003, typeof(GenericDerivedClass<string>))]
    public abstract class GenericBaseClass<T> : BaseClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public T ResponseProperty
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public GenericBaseClass()
        {
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1004, typeof(DerivedClass1))]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1005, typeof(DerivedClass2))]
    public abstract class GenericDerivedClass<T> : GenericBaseClass<T>
    {
        public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }

        public GenericDerivedClass()
        {

        }
    }
```

Finally these classes are implemented by two closed constructed non generic classes

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class DerivedClass1 : GenericDerivedClass<string>             
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Order = 6)]
        public int DerivedClass1Property { set; get; }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class DerivedClass2 : GenericDerivedClass<object>
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Order = 7)]
        public int DerivedClass2Property { set; get; }
    }
```

I have written the following test method to serialize these and it is giving me error.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeDeserializeAndCompare()
    {            

        DerivedClass2 i = new DerivedClass2() { BaseProperty1 = 1, BaseProperty2 = 2, DerivedClass2Property = 3, ResponseProperty = new Object() };
        using (var file = System.IO.File.Create("test.bin"))
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(file, i);
        }

        using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
        {
            var o = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass2>(file);
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is

ProtoBuf.ProtoException: A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy (CapitalIQ.DataGet.UnitTests.DataSetUnitTest+DerivedClass2) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy

Is this a limitation of protobuf .net or am I doing something incorrect. I am using r282 version.

Thanks
Shobhit

Comment: Something like that should work. I'm on "kids duty" at the moment, but will look later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with all attributes, the included type information on attributes apply to all closed types from the generic type definition. Thus, what you have actually defined (to protobuf-net) is:

```
BaseClass
: GenericBaseClass<object>
 : GenericDerivedClass<object>
  : DerivedClass1
  : DerivedClass2
 : GenericDerivedClass<string>
  : DerivedClass1
  : DerivedClass2
: GenericBaseClass<string>
 : GenericDerivedClass<object>
  : DerivedClass1
  : DerivedClass2
 : GenericDerivedClass<string>
  : DerivedClass1
  : DerivedClass2
```

As you can see, there are lots of duplicates - which is clearly confusing. Since attribute arguments can't use type parameters, this would leave the option of adding some kind of odd predicate mechanism, which is IMO pretty confusing. IMO, it would be a better idea to model this manually (removing the `ProtoInclude` attributes). I *suspect* your intended model is:

```
BaseClass
: GenericBaseClass<object>
 : GenericDerivedClass<object>
  : DerivedClass2
: GenericBaseClass<string>
 : GenericDerivedClass<string>
  : DerivedClass1
```

protobuf-net can work with that, but to *explain* the model requires "v2" and the `RuntimeTypeModel`:

Note also that `object` is a bit of a problem for protobuf; protobuf-net can fake around it with the dynamic-type option, but that is... not ideal. It certainly can't serialize an `object`, so for the test I've substituted a string. Note also that `BaseProperty1`, `BaseProperty2` and `AdditionalProperty` are not currently marked for serialization, but can be trivially.

Anyway:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseClass)]
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(GenericBaseClass<object>))
    .AddSubType(11, typeof(GenericBaseClass<string>));

RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GenericBaseClass<object>)]
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(GenericDerivedClass<object>));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GenericBaseClass<object>)][5].DynamicType = true; // object!
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GenericDerivedClass<object>)]
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(DerivedClass2));

RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GenericBaseClass<string>)]
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(GenericDerivedClass<string>));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GenericDerivedClass<string>)]
    .AddSubType(10, typeof(DerivedClass1));

DerivedClass2 i = new DerivedClass2() { BaseProperty1 = 1, BaseProperty2 = 2, DerivedClass2Property = 3, ResponseProperty = "some string" };
using (var file = System.IO.File.Create("test.bin"))
{
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(file, i);
}

using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
{
    var o = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass2>(file);
}
```

You don't *have* to use `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` - in fact, I recommend using (and caching) a separate type-model; but `Serializer.Serialize` points at the default model. If you create a custom model (`TypeModel.Create`) just store it somewhere and use the `Serialize` etc from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply!! Given that the example was just a branch of more complex class hierarchy, manually creating the typeModel can get really complicated. And also my bad, I just used object as type parameter as an example. We instead have other object filling the T param. I will give it a shot and see if I could automate using reflection. But otherwise I think there must be some way we could represent such hierarchies using attributes.

Comment: I bumped into this exception after copying an incorrect KnownType attribute that was for a child of a child class.  Would be useful if the exception text contained the duplicate class if possible.